# This single line "import seaborn as sns" dumps a dataframe to standard out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

This is literally the only command I'm running:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

When I run that single line of code the computer prints out a dataframe from a previous program:

```
# MEAN
A12    42.297308
A1     42.044986
A6     42.966379
Name: MEAN, dtype: float64
```

As well as an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PLOTS/seaborn.py", line 40, in <module>
    sns.barplot(x = 'X', y = 'Y', data = plotMe)
AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'barplot'
```

It's like it's running another script on the computer that I wrote.  I've rebooted my computer multiple times.  Powered off and unplugged it for a while... etc.  The same thing happens when I either run it as an interactive shell:

```
python
>>> import seaborn as sns
```

or put that single line in a script and run it that way.

`python test.py`

Any clue what's going on? I'm running Python 3.6.9

Comment: is there some file you wrote called `seaborn.py`? specifically at `PLOTS/seaborn.py`??

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  I'm a little surprised that gets called even when simply opening the interactive shell.   I guess you have to be careful of everything that exists in every sub-directory which is a little concerning.  Seems like an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's like it's running another script on the computer that I wrote

It *is* running another script you (probably) wrote. It's running `PLOTS/seaborn.py`. When you import a package or modules, Python searches a range of places of that module (the search paths are stored in sys.path). The first place it looks is the current working directory. Importing a script executes it, hence what you see is the result of `PLOTS/seaborn.py`.

For this reason, it is a good idea not to save files with the same names as packages you want to import! Just rename or move `PLOTS/seaborn.py` and you should be fine.